# MySQL SP with transaction correct syntax with in parameters

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, transactions

To quite simply put how my SP looks it is basically like this atleast syntax wise

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `info_insert_or_update` $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `info_insert_or_update` (
    IN in_id bigint,
    IN in_name varchar(150),
    IN in_details varchar(150))

START TRANSACTION;
    INSERT INTO infos (id, name)
VALUES (in_id, in_name)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name = in_name;

INSERT INTO details (details_id, details)
VALUES(in_id,
            in_details)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE details = in_details;
COMMIT;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

With this the problem is that it cant recognize the `in_` variables and i understand that that is because i need an compound statement with `BEGIN END` around everything but where ever i seem to put it it is something wrong with the syntax. So what is the correct syntax when i got this type of SP with in parameters that then has an transaction? (want transaction as i will add rollback onto it as well)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing datatype for the `in_details`-parameter and you are missing the starting `BEGIN`

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `info_insert_or_update`
$$
CREATE PROCEDURE `info_insert_or_update` (
in_id bigint,
in_name varchar(150),
in_details varchar(150)
)
BEGIN

START TRANSACTION;

INSERT INTO infos (id, name)
VALUES (in_id, in_name)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name = in_name;

INSERT INTO details (details_id, details)
VALUES(in_id, in_details)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE details = in_details;

COMMIT;


END
$$
```

Comment: oh the datatype where you a bobo when i wrote it here :) but nice spotting! And yeah the Begin worked perfectly thank you sir!